# use-case safety of html_entity_decode

Tags: php, variables, filter

I am using php to collect form data and send it to an email address. I am using php filter_vars to sanitize entries. As it is, this returns encoded html in the body of the email message. For example, *I'm* becomes `I&#39;m`

```
$message = "";
$message = $_POST["message"];
$message = filter_var($message, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
...
$Body .= $message;
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers);
```

My question is: If I use htmlspecialchars_decode in the email like `$Body .= htmlspecialchars_decode($message)`, am I undoing the sanitization and reopening a vulnerability? How would I go about safely converting the encoded html to html entities so my client can read the email?

Comment: are you storing the data on database and then show it back?

Comment: @waanofii.tech looks like its coming from `$_POST["message"]` and then to an email.

Comment: I'd look into "XSS exploit" on the web. That should help answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` is used to *Strip tags, optionally strip or encode special characters*.

So you are just stripping tags and encoding other things.  To not encode quotes use the filter flag `FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES`:

```
$message = filter_var($message, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
```

Have a look at [Sanitize Filters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php#filter.filters.sanitize) to see others, such as not encoding `&` etc.

However, `htmlspecialchars_decode($message)` should be fine because you have already stripped out HTML tags and this will only decode other entities like quotes `' "`, ampersand `&` etc.  That being said, you could just use `strip_tags($message)` in the first place that will leave quotes and ampersands alone.

Comment: Thank you for your help and thoughtful answer. I will use FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES since I'd like to omit brackets.

Comment: Then just use strip_tags and that’s it.